# Deque interface in the Collections hierarchy

Tags: java, deque, java-collections-api

In the Oracle [tutorial about `Collection` interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html), the interface hierarchy suggests that a `Deque` directly extends `Collection`.

[image]

But `Deque` extends `Queue` (there doesn't seem to be a change in this relationship across Java releases).

Any reason why this is not reflected in the hierarchy picture (e.g. the same way `SortedSet` is shown to extend `Set`)?

Comment: Nobody here will know this. Only designers from Oracle/Sun can know this therefore this is primarily opinion-based for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [The Deque Interface - The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/deque.html):

> The Deque interface is a richer abstract data type than both Stack and
>   Queue because it implements both stacks and queues at the same time.

---

You're right, `Deque` indeed extends `Queue` in Java...
But even though this actual relation exists, I reckon that the point of omitting it it this diagram is that, conceptually, a `Deque` could be seen as not only a specialisation of a `Queue`.

A `Deque` provides you with both the *last-in-first-out* principle of a `Stack` **and** the *first-in-first-out* one that a `Queue` offers, and representing only the strict actual hierarchy of these classes and interfaces could be misleading.
For example, `LinkedList` implements `Deque`... and yet, you'd probably never place it under `Deque` on a schema explaining the different types of `Collections` and the relations between them. :)